# Questioning the need for const in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js and working with some of their [code examples](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/).

I'm not sure I understand the purpose of these lines.

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // etc.
});
```

What is the purpose of `const` here?

The reason it's an issue is because I need to have several charts on the same page. So I either need to name them `ctx1`, `ctx2`, `ctx3`, etc., or remove the `const` keyword.

As far as I can tell, the only reason `ctx` is stored is so it can be passed to the `Chart` constructor, and that there's no apparent reason to save the `myChart` variable. So I don't see why either would need to be `const`, and I don't see why the `myChart` variable is even needed.

Comment: `const` creates a new _constant_ binding. it cannot be reassigned to a new value.

Comment: Is ctx referred to anywhere else? _What happens_ if you make it let and reassign it? Or inline the call and remove the variable entirely?

Comment: The code example assumes you're just making one chart, so you only have one context variable, so it might as well be `const`. If that's not your use case, you don't have to copy it exactly. It's just an example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I just copied that code from the examples. I'm not referencing it anywhere else.

Comment: @Barmar: I've been a developer for 40 years. I just don't work that much with JavaScript. I'm trying to understand why it was done the way it was so that I can best decide how I'll change it.

Comment: Do you use C? It also has `const`, and the concept is not very different (although it can also be used to make the contents of arrays and structures constant, which is often more useful). There's nothing fancy or JS-specific going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I can tell, the only reason ctx is stored is so it can be
> passed to the Chart constructor,

That's one reason, yes. Usually developers want to save the `ctx` as well, as you never know when you might need it. It's a convention.

> there's no apparent reason to save the myChart variable.

If you don't ever need to do anything with `myChart`, you don't HAVE TO save it. I would. It's a matter of preference.

> So I don't see why either would need to be const

It's a good practise to have all variables marked as `const`, if they are never modified in your code or should never be modified. It probably wouldn't break anything, even if you used `let` or `var`, but in the long run and especially if you work with others, it's a very good idea to mark variables as `const` if they shouldn't be modified.

> I don't see why the myChart variable is even needed.

Well they've given you a one way to do it. You don't have to follow it strictly. It would be a bad use of time to make multiple examples with tiny variations to suit everyone's specific needs.

> The reason it's an issue is because I need to have several charts on
> the same page. So I either need to name them ctx1, ctx2, ctx3, etc.,
> or remove the const keyword.

I wouldn't remove the const, but do that ctx1, ctx2, ... solution instead. One ctx for each chart. That's simply the reality of your situation. The example is for one chart and if you need multiple, you need multiple ctx's.